# Chrome дублирует запрос

Tags: google-chrome

Не знаю сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким, но проблема следующая. Когда я пишу адрес сайта в поисковую строку, еще не нажав на Enter, Chrome уже на фоне ПОЛНОЦЕННО с html и заголовками грузит сайт, вычислил я это через сниффер. И когда я нажимаю Enter чтобы открыть сайт, Chrome снова отправляет запрос, грузит все заново и в итоге открывает сайт. Что я вижу в логах.

`1.1.1.1.1 - - [20/Nov/2018:11:11:57 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 20349 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"`

`1.1.1.1.1 - - [20/Nov/2018:11:12:00 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 18991 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36"`

Видны абсолютно одинаковые запросы, с разницей в 3 секунды, т.е пока я нажимал на Enter старый запрос еще завершился, а новый только начал грузиться ибо у меня apache позволяет только одно соединение.

Самая большая проблема в том, что первый фоновой запрос еще до нажатия на Enter сервером уже отработан, и куки токен который я использую для авторизации пользователя сервером обновляется, пишется в БД и шлется назад клиенту в заголовках, только вот когда я жму Enter запрос шлется-то со старым токеном, т.е куки в браузере еще не обновились, в итоге юзер остается не опознан. И чтобы получить новые куки из браузера, нужно нажать F5 чтобы все синхронизировалось.

Короче бред какой-то. В других браузерах такого нет. Нашел описание данной проблемы тут (последние ответы) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432378/chrome-sends-a-request-multiple-times

Решения не вижу.

Comment: Видимо надо пересмотреть авторизацию и не использовать постоянного обновления куки. Вы никогда не можете быть уверены, что клиент получил сформированную куку и не решит использовать предыдущую. В любой момент в сети может произойти все что угодно и отосланная (и запомненная вами в БД) кука может быть не получена клиентом. Большинство систем авторизации выдают куку один раз - после проверки пароля и далее е не меняют при каждом обращении

Comment: @Mike они и не меняются при каждом обращении. Куки обновляются только если нет временной сессии которая действует до закрытия браузера. Если браузер закрыть, то я токен обновляю, ибо юзер мог 2 дня не заходить и это не безопасно.

Comment: тогда не понимаю чем вам мешает первое обращение хрома. почему первое обращение что то обновляет в БД такое, что мешает второму обращению ?

Comment: потому, что второе обращение шлет старый токен, и юзер получает страницу как будто он гость, но если он обновит страницу, то новая кука полученная с первого запроса уже будет действительна.

Comment: все это происходит очень быстро, вы сами сказали, что кука еще не сформирована, вот и происходит рассинхронизация данных. Если не жать сразу Enter, а подождать хотя бы на 1-2 сек дольше, то все работает. Вся дилемма здесь из-за дублирования запроса который вообще не нужен.

Comment: Повторяю свой первый коммент: вы никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах не должны полагаться на то, что клиент получит куку, которую вы высылаете. Старый токен должен оставаться действительным некоторое время после того, как вы подумали, что обновили его. Сервер должен быть готов обработать любой запрос от клиента повторно

Comment: @Mike я понял вас. Значит нужно при обновлении делать 2 куки, и при повторном запросе сравнивать и удалять старую?

Comment: Надо в БД хранить токены так, что бы они от туда не удалялись сразу после того, как вы их вышлите клиенту. При нестабильной связи клиент вполне может сделать даже 5 запросов подряд. И не надо удалять токен из БД во время отсылки ответов никогда. Если вы боитесь, что таблица будет слишком большой, то удаляйте устаревшие токены какой нибудь отдельной процедурой, по времени их устаревания

Comment: Может оказаться полезным фиксировать в таблице факт обмена старого токена с указанием нового, что бы при повторном обращении просто вернуть этот самый новый

Comment: @Mike сердечно благодарю за ответ. Буду разбираться